# add items into two arrays (future and past dates) based on date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am trying to find a way to sort posts into two arrays: upcoming and current (upcoming posts are in the future and current have already been posted).

All posts have a scheduledPubDate that is a date string in the format `YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00`. and todays date has to be a Date object as it will need to stay relevent (I am using moment())

Is it possible to compare these two different things without having to use a .split and compare the month / day /year separately

```
 angular.forEach(data.items, function (key, index) {
   if (moment(key.scheduledPubDate) > moment()) {
       $scope.upcomingPosts.push(item[index]);
   } else if (moment(key.scheduledPubDate) <= moment()) {
       $scope.currentPosts.push(item[index]);
   };
 });
```

Comment: While this isn't a complete answer, you should consider using `ng-repeat` with a filter and a directive to do this rather than a forEach - look into that

Comment: I didnt think of doing that. however it wont work for me this time as I am not displaying the data but rather separating them into two arrays but I appreciate the reminder! I always forget about filters

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy
Pretty sure you can do ng-repeat on non-UI stuff too.  It just returns a copy of the array sorted by the model parameter you include

Comment: You can parse a date to a string using: `moment(theDateStr, theFormatStr);`. Once you've got that, you can just compare dates using `<` or `>`. There's nothing built in to compare string dates, you need to parse them.

Comment: The string has no timezone, do you want it treated as UTC or local? Standards differ on what to do so you can't rely on that.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I picked the answer that I used but each of you really helped me understand using dates a lot better so I upvoted you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the date format of the string

```
 var format = "YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00";
 angular.forEach(data.items, function (key, index) {
   if (moment(key.scheduledPubDate, format) > moment()) {
     $scope.upcomingPosts.push(item[index]);
   } else if (moment(key.scheduledPubDate, format) <= moment()) {
     $scope.currentPosts.push(item[index]);
   };
 });
```

Working example (See the console.log): http://jsbin.com/fejaxiguce/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's built-in [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) will help you here.

```
var date = Date.parse('2014-01-21T12:45:13');
date < Date.now() // true
```

For the purpose of an example, let's assume `items` is an array of posts:

```
var items = [{
    scheduledPubDate: '2014-01-21T12:45:13'
    // ...other keys here
}, {
    scheduledPubDate: '2017-03-01T15:21:00'
} // ...and so on
];
```

Then a `reduce` operation over `items` can categorize the posts:

```
var posts = items.reduce(function (memo, item) {
    memo[Date.parse(item.scheduledPubDate) <= Date.now() ? 'current' : 'upcoming'].push(item);
    return memo;
}, { current: [], upcoming: [] });
```

Now `posts.current` will contain an array of all posts from `items` whose `scheduledPubDate` is before the current date, and `posts.upcoming` will contain an array of all scheduled posts.

*Edited to use `Date.parse`, to avoid unreliable behavior pointed out by RobG. This requires that all dates be in the `YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00` format you specified; if that is not the case, another solution will be required.*

Comment: There is no "Date class" in javascript. There are [*Date* objects](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9). Do not use the Date constructor to parse strings, it is unreliable. The format you propose will be treated as local by some script engines (ES5 compliant), UTC in others (ECMA-262 ed 6 draft compliant) and NaN or something entirely different in the rest.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to use `Date.parse` instead, since the question states all date strings are in the format `YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00`.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want the string treated as UTC, a simple parser for that is:

```
// Expected format YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00
function parseUTC(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]));
}
```

Note that this doesn't allow for invalid dates. If needed, an extra line if code is required. So now you can do:

```
if (parseUTC(key.scheduledPubDate) > new Date()) // or Date.now()
```

You really don't need moment.js for this.

Answer (score 0):

First create an array of elements, in any order, and then use the .sort() method.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Just substitute the above logic with your own. a and b above can be objects.

Comment: that is a good idea but im not trying to put them in an order per say. I am more concerned with  1) how one can compare a date in a different format 2) is it possible to make a string into a date or 3) is it possible to compare these two different things without having to use a .split and compare the month / day /year separately

Comment: Please don't reference W3Schools. Use the [*language specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) for normative references and [*Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) or similar for examples.